# Merge two name value pairs in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Is it possible to merge two name value pairs into one in an object? Can it be done by a foreach or something? I have seen examples of merging two objects to one but not merging name value pairs within an object of an array.

Original array:

```
[
    {
        "id": "10bf820c19869d1097b0f056c924d9f8",
        "text1": "Text A",
        "text2": "Option"
    },
    {
        "id": "7b6a8f291986955097b0f056c924d981",
        "text1": "Text B",
        "text2": "Option"
    },
    {
        "id": "99ca5a64b45a551097b07caca12ca710",
        "text1": "Text C",
        "text2": "Option"
    }
]
```

To be:

```
[
    {
        "id": "10bf820c19869d1097b0f056c924d9f8",
        "text": "Text A - Option"
    },
    {
        "id": "7b6a8f291986955097b0f056c924d981",
        "text": "Text B - Option"
    },
    {
        "id": "99ca5a64b45a551097b07caca12ca710",
        "text": "Text A - Option"
    }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map()` to do it

```js
let data = [
    {
        "id": "10bf820c19869d1097b0f056c924d9f8",
        "text1": "Text A",
        "text2": "Option"
    },
    {
        "id": "7b6a8f291986955097b0f056c924d981",
        "text1": "Text B",
        "text2": "Option"
    },
    {
        "id": "99ca5a64b45a551097b07caca12ca710",
        "text1": "Text C",
        "text2": "Option"
    }
]

let result = data.map(d => ({'id':d.id,'text':d.text1 + ' - ' + d.text2}))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an array and the behavior seems to be consistent ("text1" + "text2") you can use `map`

```
baseArray.map(element => ({id: element.id, text: `${element.text1} - ${element.text2}` }))
```

Comment: Many thanks! You guys have pointed me in the right direction, and I need to take a look into the JavaScript Array map() method to transform elements in an array.

Just what I needed! :)

Comment: @Jonis Is my answer doesn't work for you?

Comment: @lucumt Yes, both answers are working just fine! :)